# Can you open an external application in Python? How?

Tags: python

I am currently making a terminal based Python program. I was wondering if it was possible to open external applications like Google Chrome, Firefox, Games or Mail. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: try looking into `os.popen` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.popen()`

```
import os
os.popen('firefox')
```

or `subprocess.call()`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["firefox"])
```